# Resizing PopupWindow depending on changing content height

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a PopupWindow that contains a ViewPager, in each fragment of which there is a RecyclerView.
Popup's layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6mm"
        android:paddingTop="1mm"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout.Tab"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTabSecondary" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabs" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragments has same layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to change PopupWindow height, when I put new items inside of fragments recyclerview?

**Update:** Just use `PopupWindow.update()`